# set initial state to another state/prop

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-state

Is there a way to make an initial state equal the length of another state?

I have an example below of what i'd like to achieve where 'options_counter' needs to be equal to the length of the initial number of items in options which is an array within the state:

```
this.state = {
            options: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    label: 'Industrial Truck and Tractor Operators',
                    value: '53-7051',
                   ,
                    tooltip_text: 'Operate industrial trucks or tractors equipped to move materials around a warehouse, storage yard, factory, construction site, or similar location. Excludes “Logging Equipment Operators" (45-4022).',
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    label: 'Order Clerks',
                    value: '43-4151',

                    tooltip_text: 'Receive and process incoming orders for materials, merchandise, classified ads, or services such as repairs, installations, or rental of facilities. Generally receives orders via mail, phone, fax, or other electronic means. Duties include informing customers of receipt, prices, shipping dates, and delays; preparing contracts; and handling complaints. Excludes "Dispatchers, Except Police, Fire, and Ambulance" (43-5032) who both dispatch and take orders for services.',
                },
            ],
            value: null,
            styles: { //container style is working
              marginTop:"2em",
              marginLeft: "2em",
              borderStyle: "solid",
              borderWidth: ".1em",
              borderBottom:"none",
              borderRight: "solid",
              width:"19em",
              textAlign: "justify",
              backgroundColor: "white",
              boxShadow: "3px 6px 5px #9E9E9E"
            },

            options_counter: this.state.options.length,

        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to set it initially like so from inside the component I am rendering:

```
<div onLoad={()=>{this.props.setProps({options_counter:this.props.options.length})}} style={this.props.styles}>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work.  Take a look at `getter` methods in Javascript: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_accessors.asp

```
this.state = {
    options: initialOptions || [],
    get optionsCount() {
        return this.options.length;
    }
}
```

And to use it:

```
const { optionsCount } = this.state;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would directly use a function:

```js
this.state = {
            options: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    label: 'Industrial Truck and Tractor Operators',
                    value: '53-7051',
                    tooltip_text: 'Operate industrial trucks or tractors equipped to move materials around a warehouse, storage yard, factory, construction site, or similar location. Excludes “Logging Equipment Operators" (45-4022).',
                },
                {
                    id: 1,
                    label: 'Order Clerks',
                    value: '43-4151',

                    tooltip_text: 'Receive and process incoming orders for materials, merchandise, classified ads, or services such as repairs, installations, or rental of facilities. Generally receives orders via mail, phone, fax, or other electronic means. Duties include informing customers of receipt, prices, shipping dates, and delays; preparing contracts; and handling complaints. Excludes "Dispatchers, Except Police, Fire, and Ambulance" (43-5032) who both dispatch and take orders for services.',
                },
            ],
            value: null,
            styles: { 
              marginTop:"2em",
              marginLeft: "2em",
              borderStyle: "solid",
              borderWidth: ".1em",
              borderBottom:"none",
              borderRight: "solid",
              width:"19em",
              textAlign: "justify",
              backgroundColor: "white",
              boxShadow: "3px 6px 5px #9E9E9E"
            },

            options_counter: () => this.state.options.length,

        };
        
console.log(
    this.state.options_counter()
);
```

Comment: Would there be a way to set it using the componentDidRender hook inside a component that actually renders out the options as a set of divs?

Comment: What is the error ? In the above code snippet it works. @monsterpiece

Answer (score 0):

Use componentDidMount() for this functionality.
The componentDidMount() method is called after the component is rendered.
So it would always set the state correcly before you begin using it.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        options_counter: 0
    };
}
```

Then, change this initial value of 0 in componentDidMount()

```
componentDidMount(){
  this.setState({
    options_counter: this.state.options.length
  });
}
```

Read more here : [Reactjs Lifecycle: componentDidMount()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)